# Disable setsockopt(IPV6_V6ONLY)

Tags: linux, ipv6, ipv4

I love mapped addresses, and some bad software (lighttpd) believes I'm wrong - in fact, the only config key they let me change is whether or not it'll call `setsockopt(IPV6_V6ONLY, true)`. disabling that config doesn't explicitly set `IPV6_V6ONLY` to `false`.

To make everyone happy, I'd like to disable the program's ability to `setsockopt(IPV6_V6ONLY)`, while keeping `/proc/sys/net/ipv6/bindv6only` as `0`.

Is there any way to do this in plain old linux?

Answer (score 0):

Since most programs make such calls through libc, use $LD_PRELOAD to intercept them:

1. Write a shared library (a .so file) that provides your own implementation of `setsockopt()`.
2. In your implementation, you can check the parameters and call the original function, or don't. (Use `dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, …)` to get a pointer to the "original" function so that you can call it.)

   ```
   int frob(const char *path) {
       static int (*real_frob)(const char *);
       if (!real_frob)
           real_frob = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "frob");
       return real_frob(path);
   }
   ```
3. After compiling the .c file into a .so, set the $LD_PRELOAD environment variable for the daemon to your new library's path.